# labels are printed when set_xticklabels called

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

**Issue:**

All labels are getting printed when setting the rotation for the x-axis label using `set_xticklabels`.

**Code**

```
winner_freq = pd.DataFrame(player_match.winner.value_counts().reset_index())
winner_freq_plot = sns.barplot(x='index', y='winner', data=winner_freq)
winner_freq_plot.set_xticklabels(winner_freq_plot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Fix that I tried**

I don't have any idea how to fix it and googled but no answer, so I took the labels separately in a list and feed inside the `set_xticklabels` but still no luck.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not really a mistake, but rather, a characteristic of `matplotlib`, which `seaborn` uses. Most of its functions return values that in some way represent the computations that they have performed.

In this case, `set_xticklabels` modifies the *tick labels*, which are drawn with `Text` objects. It is those `Text` objects, collected in a `list`, that are returned.

What you perceive as the labels being "printed" is simply your Jupyter notebook representing that `list` as text.

If you do not wish to see this, **use a semicolon at the end of the last statement in a cell to prevent its output.**

Alternatively, you can assign the result to a throwaway variable, like this:

```
_ = winner_freq_plot.set_xticklabels(winner_freq_plot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

That said, note that `_` normally binds to the *last return value*, and you will override that by doing so.

Another alternative is to simply append a `pass` statement to your code. Since Jupyter will render the return value of the last statement in the cell, and `pass` returns nothing, you will not get any output.

Comment: Use a semicolon at the end of the last statement in a cell to prevent its output. There  are many questions and answers on this already, so better vote to close instead of answering again.

Comment: @gmds Thanks for the help. It works well and also ImportanceOfBeingErnest answer is very simple and it also works well.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest not sure I follow what the "last cell" is. Can you make an example?

Comment: `ax.set_xticklabels(...);` <- line ends by a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using jupyter notebook just

ax.set_xticklabels(...)**;** <- line ends by a semicolon.